# Why is my component breaking if I reference a method in `onClick` within a `map`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The most stupid thing is happening with my code right now. I have a list of items render in the DOM, I need to put a button in order to call another function, if I put the button like this `<button></button>` everything is ok, but if I assign a function to that button, then everything goes down `<button onClick={function}></button>` I will show you my code, look

```
@connectToStores
export default class Dealers extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  static propTypes = {
    title : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal : false,
    }
  }

  static getStores () {
    return [ GetDealersStore ];
  }

  static getPropsFromStores () {
    return GetDealersStore.getState();
  }
  render () {
    let dealersInfo;
    if (this.props.dealerData !== null) {
      dealersInfo = this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map(function(dealer) {
        return (<div key={dealer.DealerId} style={Styles.dealerCard}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader title={dealer.NickName}
                            subtitle={dealer.DealerId}
                            avatar={dealer.Picture}/>
                <CardText>
                  <FloatingActionButton> ////////////////////////
                    <IconAdd />    //////THIS IS THE BUTTON/////
                  </FloatingActionButton>//////////////////////
                </CardText>
              </Card>
            </div>
        );
      });
    } else {
      dealersInfo = <p>Loading . . .</p>;
    }

    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Column><h4>Dealers</h4></Column>
        </Row>
        <div style={Styles.mainCont}>
          {dealersInfo}
        </div>
      </Grid>
    );
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
  }

  _openUpdateDealer = () => {
    console.log(123);
  }
}
```

as you can see there is an statement

```
if (this.props.dealerData !== null) {
   ...
}else {
   dealersInfo = <p>Loading . . .</p>;
}
```

as I pasted the code above everything works awesome, but if I add `<FloatingActionButton onClick={this._openUpdateDealer.bind(this)}><IconAdd /></FloatingActionButton>` then everything goes down, all I see in the screen is `Loading . . .` which is the `else` in the statement above.

So, I want to know, what is going on with react here ?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console? What does the button element look like when you view it in the DOM inspector?

Comment: @Pointy there is no errors in the console. Without the function attached to the button, the button looks normal. But with the function attached, I am unable to visualize the button, only `Loading . . .`

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rendering the button in the middle of a `.map` operation:

```
this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map(function(dealer) {
```

which uses a different value for `this`; thus, `this.props` doesn't exist inside the function. I would expect to see `cannot read property dealerData of undefined` in the browser console.

You need to use [the optional `thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map(function(dealer) {
  // ...
}, this);
```

[bind the mapping function to `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) manually:

```
this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map(function(dealer) {
  // ...
}.bind(this));
```

or use [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (since you're using ES6 features):

```
this.props.dealerData.dealersData.map((dealer) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: where should I use the arrow function ? I mean, I am using the arrow function `_openUpdateDealer = () => {...}`, where do you say I have to use it ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer Arrow functions keep lexical this, so you'd use it in the function that's losing `this`. Replace `.map(function(dealer) {` with `.map((dealer) => {`

Comment: able to help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084147/update-component-after-a-new-prop-comes-up) ?