# React linkState form

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog

**What I want:**
I want to create a modal form in order to edit a table.
I click on edit at the end of the line of my table, a modal form opens, I can edit my input values, and save or close.
*But I would like, when I update my form in my modal, ==> the table behind the modal updates itself.*

**What I did:**
Everything is working, except the update "in live" of my table.

**My code:**

```
const Trigger = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      show: false,
      name: this.props.name,
      start: this.props.start,
      end: this.props.end,
      id: this.props.id
    };
  },
  save: function(){
    var data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      start: this.state.start,
      end: this.state.end,
      id: this.state.id
    };
    $.ajax({
      ...
    });
  },
  handleNameChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  },
  handleStartChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({ start: event.target.value });
  },
  handleEndChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({ end: event.target.value });
  },
  render() {
    let close = () => this.setState({ show: false});
    var name = this.state.name;
    var start = this.state.start;
    var end = this.state.end;
    return (
      <div className="modal-container">
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          bsSize="large"
          onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true})}
        >
          Edit
        </Button>
        <Modal
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={close}
          container={this}
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">Edit Presentation</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
          <form className="form-horizontal">
              <Input type="text" label="Name" labelClassName="col-xs-2" wrapperClassName="col-xs-10" value={name} onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
              <Input type="text" label="Start" labelClassName="col-xs-2" wrapperClassName="col-xs-10" value={start} onChange={this.handleStartChange}/>
              <Input type="text" label="End" labelClassName="col-xs-2" wrapperClassName="col-xs-10" value={end} onChange={this.handleEndChange}/>
          </form>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.save}>Save</Button>
            <Button onClick={close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Presentations = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
  loadPresentationsFromServer: function(){
    AJAX...
            this.setState({presentations_parse: data});     
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      presentations_parse: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadPresentationsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadPresentationsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function(){
    var presentations = this.state.presentations_parse.map(function(presentation) {
      return (
        <tr key={presentation.objectId}>
          <td >#</td>
          <td >{presentation.name}</td>
          <td >{presentation.start.iso}</td>
          <td >{presentation.end.iso}</td>
           <td ><Trigger id={presentation.objectId} name={presentation.name} start={presentation.start.iso} end={presentation.end.iso}/></td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

const tableInstance = (
      <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {presentations}
          </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
    return (
      tableInstance
    );
  }}
);
```

**The problem:**
I try to use linkState, I included `mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin]`.
I wrote `valueLink={this.linkState('presentation.name')}` inside the map function.
The problem is this.linkState is undefined.
I can't figure out how to implement `this.linkState('...?...')`, where to write it, because I use a map function.
I don't know how to link the linkState with the presentation.   (presentation**s** = {presentation *1*, presentation *2*, presentation *n*})

**EDIT 1**
The problem doesn't come from LinkedStateMixin, because I tried this code and it works:

```
var DisplayContainer2 = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            value:'My Value'
        }
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div className="DisplayContainer">
                <h4>{this.state.value}</h4>
                <InputBox2 valueLink={this.linkState('value')} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var InputBox2 = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (<input type="text" valueLink={this.props.valueLink} />)
    }
});
```

So I think it is because I write this.linkState in the map function.
But I don't know where else to write it.
Any idea?

**EDIT 2:**
I change my code here, to use the optional thisArg parameter in map.
I understand the problem, I no longer have the problem `this.linkState is undefined`.
But two other problems:

1. Uncaught Error: Minified exception
2. How can I use multiple linkState? I want to use one for each column of my table.

Comment: Are you sure your are getting the mixin correctly ? according to the doc it seems you ahve to install it separately and get the module. var LinkedStateMixin = require('react-addons-linked-state-mixin');

Comment: Yes I'm sure mixin is correctly installed.
Another code works.
(Cf EDIT 1 in the post)

Comment: Remember that `.map` creates a new context for the function passed to it, and `this` doesn't point to what you think it does unless you use `map(function(...) { ... }.bind(this))`, use the optional `thisArg` parameter to `map`, or, if using ES6, use arrow functions. See [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33030325/62082) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a simple scope issue.

Try it this way

```
render(or wtv function): function() {
    var self = this;
    newarray = someStuff.map(function() {
        self.MyHigherScopeMixin ...

    })
}
```

That or use the call/apply functions.

Hope it helps